# Correct way to handle change in settings for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, phphotolibrary

If the user did not allow access to photo album at the start, I will prompt with a pop up with Cancel and Settings to choose from. If he chooses settings, it will bring him to settings page where he can enable camera and photo Library for the app. However, as soon as the user toggles the camera or photo library switch in settings, my app crashes with "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9" printout. Below is the code for my popup

```
    @IBAction func cameraBarBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {

    let photoAuthStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

    switch photoAuthStatus {

    case .Authorized:
        presentFusumaCameraVC()

    case .Denied, .Restricted :

        showNeedPhotoAlbumAccessPopup()

    case .NotDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (authStatus: PHAuthorizationStatus) in
            switch authStatus {
            case .Authorized:
                self.presentFusumaCameraVC()

            case .Denied, .Restricted :
                self.showNeedPhotoAlbumAccessPopup()

            case .NotDetermined:
                print("Shouldnt get to here")
            }
        })
    }
}

func showNeedPhotoAlbumAccessPopup() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enable Photo Album Access", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
        let settingsUrl = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
        if let url = settingsUrl {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    })
    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

What would be the correct way to handle this so that the user can go back to the app and begin selecting the photos after toggling the switch?

Comment: What is the implementation of your PHPhotolibrary.authorizationStatus() method?

Comment: I did not implement PHPhotolibrary. authorizationStatus() myself. it is from apple's PHPPhotoLibrary: NSObject class

Comment: What is the value of photoAuthStatus?

Comment: At the moment that my phone is authorised for photo acess the value is 3 for photoAuthStatus.rawValue and photoAuthStatus.hasValue. What are you thinking?

Comment: I was thinking you may not be getting the correct status. But now I'm wondering what you mean by "as soon as the user toggles the camera or photo library switch in settings". Are you saying the act of toggling the switch is what crashes your app? If you have he app stopped and toggle the switch, then open the app, does it function properly?

Comment: I tested it just then. With my device connected to xcode, when my app is enabled with photo access, I push the home button to get to settings and toggled the photos access in settings for my app. As soon as I toogle, the crash is shown at class AppDelegate with Thread1: signal SIGKILL

Comment: Sounds like it may be the behavior of the operating system and there's nothing you can do to prevent it.

Comment: Instagram seems to manage it alright though

Comment: Looks to me like Instagram is killed as well.

Comment: Actually you are correct.

Answer (score 5):

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/710/) says the following:

> - If permissions changes, app is quit
> - Background task expiration handler is called, if registered
> - iOS then kills the application

Haven't seen a way around so far.